# Github Actions: How to create multiline env variable for serveral jobs

Tags: github, continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions

I want to add serveral lines to a code file. And this in various jobs. So I created one job which create a text file and upload it.

```
create_file:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:      
    - shell: bash
      run: |
        cat << EOF > data.txt
        A = "..."
        B = "..."
        C = "..."
        ...
        EOF
    - name: Create data file
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@1
      with:
        name: configuration
        path: data.txt
```

At the next job I upload the file and want to append this lines to a code file.

```
test_file:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: [create_file]
  steps:
  - name: Download file     
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
    with:
      name: configuration
      path: configuration/data.txt
  - shell: bash
     run: |
       cat configuration/data.txt >> main.py
       python main.py
```

I have the problem that the second job is too fast and searches after the `data.txt` file before it is already uploaded and how I could handle the to append content. The command `echo "..." >> main.py` for each line would be very annoying.

**Update:**
Now I get for the job `data.txt` following error messages:

```
 Download action repository 'actions/upload-artifact@1'
 ##[warning]Failed to download action 'https://api.github.com/repos/actions/upload-artifact/tarball/1'. Error Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
 ...
 ##[error]Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

Comment: So want to have both jobs executed in parallel but the 2nd to finish after the first? Otherwise you could add a `needs create_file` to the `test_file` job. See: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @МихаилПавлов Sadly no.

Comment: @ikreb I got one. Used shell pipe with `tr`. `echo ${{secrets.DATA}} | tr ' ' '\n'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was very stupid. The line `actions/upload-artifact@1` should be `actions/upload-artifact@v1`.